# Checking uniqueness of OperationId when using c.CustomOperationIds?

Tags: swashbuckle

At the moment, if you use the following

```
c.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc =>
{
    return apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo) ? methodInfo.Name : null;
});
```

And, by programmer mistake, you have 2 methods with same name, you are not warned that you violate OpenAPI spec

Is there a way to add a check ?

I was thinking to either

- at the end of generation like "2 operations with id {0}"
- when swashbuckle calls CustomOperationId "selector", have a hook to access already defined operations

Thanks for your time

P.S : using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I've found a workaround: use an operation filter that will throw an exception if OperationId is already used

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Service.Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Guarantee that OperationId is not already used
    /// </summary>
    public class SwaggerUniqueOperationId : IOperationFilter
    {
        private readonly HashSet<string> ids = new HashSet<string>();

        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (operation.OperationId != null)
            {
                if (ids.Contains(operation.OperationId))
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"There are 2 operations with same OperationId {operation.OperationId}");
                ids.Add(operation.OperationId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not ideal at all because the error message is pretty vague and it is a runtime error, but this is better than providing an OpenApi spec that violates this unique OperationId constraint...